# Pathname Issue for a File in Desktop of my MacBook for a ML project

Tags: python, macos, machine-learning, pathname

Hope everyone is doing well in these weird times.
I can't seem to find the pathname to my file.

```
import os

IMG_PATH = /Users/darthvader/Desktop/archive
```

This is the error when I use it in Google Colab/jupyter notebook :(

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/darthvader/Desktop/archive'
```

I am using a MacBook Pro. The file is on my desktop. The main file (named archive, downloaded from Kaggle) has 3 smaller files within it: 1) brain_tumor_dataset, 2) no, 3) yes.

I have attached a picture of the main file showing it in my main desktop view as well as the files within it.

[Main File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Opnfr.png)

[Smaller Files within the Main File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ9G5.png)

Thank you so much to whoever takes the time to help me with this

Comment: The supplied images do not really help, for example the archive folder you have shown an image of could be anywhere on your mac, the image just simply shows an archive directory is somewhere.

Providing these are in the correct location, what permissions does archive have (as well as the parent folders), does the user the python script being run under have relevant permissions to the folder?

Comment: these are from the desktop of my MacBook, the user (me) has permission to all my folders

Answer (score 0):

If your path is correct for sure, then try putting quotes around this line

```
IMG_PATH = /Users/darthvader/Desktop/archive
```

and change it to

```
IMG_PATH = '/Users/darthvader/Desktop/archive'
```

And this is what you have already done, then a bit more clarification is required to solve your issue.